# Storing byte patterns in c++

Tags: c++, cpu-word, bit, memory-address

I am currently working on a project which requires me to store a 32 bit pattern and analyze it. I need a way to store the pattern such as "1001 1001 1100 1000" in a variable where it won't get reinterpreted as a char for example.

Comment: @avakar - `uint_least32_t` is more portable. `unsigned long` even more so.

Answer (score 2):

In C++03, I would use `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` but neither is specified to be exactly 32 bit. `unsigned long` is specified to be able to hold *at least* the values [0, 2<sup>32</sup>-1], so theoretically it could be larger than 32 bits. In C++11, I'd use `uint32_t`;

for example `0000 0000 0000 0000 1001 1001 1100 1000` is `0x99c8`, where `0x` is the hexadecimal prefix.

```
uint32_t bitpattern = 0x998c
```

If the variable `bitpattern` contains the desired bit pattern and you'd like to stream it to console as a hexadecimal number, you'd use this:

```
std::cout << std::hex << bitpattern;
```

Comment: You should mention that `uint32_t` is marked as optional by the standard. To be completely safe, use `uint_least32_t`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the 32 bit patterns to int, you can also use the STL container `<bitset>` to do the job:

```
std::bitset<32> bit(std::string("0001100111001000"));
long unsigned bit_number = bit.to_ulong();
std::string bit_string = bit.to_string();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that the pattern isn't 32 bits, right?

Since it isn't, something like

```
unsigned long pattern = 0x99c8;
```

should be very safe, you'd be hard pressed to find a platform where `unsigned long` is less than 16 bits. Lke Armen said, if you have `uint32_t`, use it.

Comment: `long` is always at least 32-bits wide.

Answer (score 0):

Besides trying to use an integral type and bitmasking to create your own system, you might also want to consider a rarely-used feature that comes built-in, namely [bit fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  The definition of such a type is much like a struct, however the data type for each element is anonymous and the size is specified by the number of bits.  There is some overhead, but not much more than you'd have trying to implement it yourself; in effect, you let the compiler do the work.

If you need to convert the struct back-and-forth between an integral type (such as long) you can just (ab)use reinterpret_cast:

```
struct bitSet {
  bitSet(long in1) { //ctor, eg bitSet tmpBit(input);
    *this = reinterpret_cast<bitSet>(in1);
  }
  long toLong() { //eg output=tmpBit.toLong;
    return reinterpret_cast<long>(*this);
  }

  unsigned U0 : 4;
  unsigned U1 : 4;
  unsigned U2 : 4;
  unsigned U3 : 4;
  unsigned U4 : 4;
  unsigned U5 : 4;
  unsigned U6 : 4;
  unsigned U7 : 4;
};
```

The advantage to this is that although you can't guarantee the length of an integral type, such a long, this does ensure that each element is only 4 bits long.

Comment: But it doesn't guarantee that it will actually work. The layout of the fields is **implementation defined**. You cannot assume that 8 4-bit fields will take up exactly 32 bits.